# How to handle a Domino draw game tile placement in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Im planning to make a domino draw game but im not quite sure how to handle the tile placement so that each tile snaps to each value when a player sets a domino, could any one give me an idea on how to achive this?
[Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AC3yl.png)

Answer (score 0):

This question is probably too broad.  You really need to make an attempt at implementing a solution yourself and then come back if you run into a specific problem.  However, if you really have no idea where to begin, you broadly need to do a few things:

1. Create a GameObjects for your dominoes and attach a scripts to the,
   which define their numbers, set their corresponding texture etc.
2. Create an invisible play surface which is made up of a grid representing places where tiles can be put down.
3. Add code to handle picking up, moving and putting down your dominoes.
4. In the code that handles moving and/or putting down dominoes:

   - check whether the grid location where the domino is going to be placed is valid (e.g adjacent to another domino),
   - then check adjacent grid domino values
   - For adjacent dominoes, check their orientation
   - depending on the orientation relative to the domino you are placing, check the values at the nearest or both ends of the domino
   - if the adjacent domino values match a value on the domino being moved allow it to be placed, otherwise don't allow it to be placed

In the above example, "placing" a domino would simply mean moving it to a point on the play surface grid in either a vertical or horizontal orientation.

This is a very broad overview and there are plenty of gotchas that I haven't covered which may or may not give you trouble.

*Edit: You could also do this without using a grid but it would be a little trickier when it comes to finding and inspecting adjacent dominoes.*